# Why exception is thrown at the end of this code?

Tags: c++, exception

```
int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        int n, k;
        cin >> n >> k;
        int* ar1 = new int[n];
        int* ar2 = new int[n];
        /*int ar1[n];
        int ar2[n];*/
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> ar1[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> ar2[i];
        }
        sort(ar1, ar1 + n);
        sort(ar2, ar2 + n, greater<int>());
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n, k>0; i++) {
            if (ar1[i] < ar2[i]) {
                ar1[i] = ar2[i];
                k--;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum += ar1[i];
        }
        cout << sum << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Unhandled exception at 0x77B6EC75 (ntdll.dll) in code.exe: 0xC000000D: An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.** Whenever this code is compiled for the first time, it works fine, but second time it throws an exception. I have submitted this code on codeforces and there it prints **9720301** after printing all the results correctly.

Comment: Read up on the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) - `for (int i = 0; i < n, k>0; i++)` is not doing what you think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition in this loop is wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n, k>0; i++)
```

since it might fail even when `i>=n` (the condition will evaluate `i<n`, ignore it, and only check if `k>0`).

Instead, you need to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n && k > 0; i++)
```

to check that *both* the conditions are satisfied. Otherwise, you are potentially indexing out of range of `arr1`, and `arr2`, which throws the error. (It's actually undefined behavior, so *anything* could happen).